# How to read values from firestore array with flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have following array in firestore

[image]

I am using following code to read it;

```
    List companies= [];
       fireData()  async {
  var _dataC =  await 
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('comp').doc(uida).collection('comp').get();
 var comList= await _dataC.docs.map((e) => e.get('skills')).toList();

 setState(() {
   companies=comList;
  });
  }
```

I am able to fetch records and put them in a listview builder. But these 3 names are not appearing with their index but everything is appearing in one text as
[tcs, infy, wipro]

I need to get individual elements on the list. Length of the list is showing as 1 instead of 2.

I am using following code show these in ListView builder;

```
        ListView.builder  (
        itemCount: companies.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
        return Container(
        width: size.width * 0.1,
        child:  Card(
          child: ListTile(
            leading: Text( companies[index][0], style: 
          TextStyle(color: Colors.black),),
          ),), ); })
```

With 0, i can manually access first element but i need a list view with all the elements displayed in separate cards. Please

Comment: The `comList` variable should contain the list still, so most likely the problems happens when you map it to the UI widgets. Can you edit your question to show the code where the problem occurs?

Answer (score 1):

I think by taking the list of skills, and writing it to a list, you created a `List<List>`.  So, either access it by calling skills[0][0], skills[0][1], etc or don't write it toList(), it's already a list, so you don't need to write it as such.